# Android Firebase: Compare values on device or use `equalTo` method?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list of User-IDs and I need to get the corresponding user information.
I see two approaches.

**First:**

```
user_reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
            Users users = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
            
            if (idList.contains(users.getUser_id())) {
                usersList.add(users);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Second:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < idList.size(); i++) {
    user_reference.orderByChild("user_id").equalTo(idList.get(i))
                   .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                Users users = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
                usersList.add(users);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The first seems to be inefficient, because if I have like a few thousand users, it would load every single user, also if I only need 5 of them.

However, the second approach seems to be similar, only that the comparison happens on the server-side.

---

So which option is faster?

Or are both options not the good way to go? So is there a better solution I didn't think of?

Comment: Can you show how you initialize `user_reference`? And also a snippet of the JSON at that path in the database (as text please, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second option will almost always be faster, as bandwidth is typically the largest factor to influence performance.

To get the performance gains from using a server-side query, be sure to [add an index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) to the security rules of your database. If you forget to do so, the filtering will be done client-side in the SDK, and it will write a warning to your logcat output telling you to add an index.